# Is Sam Malone referencing another piece of popular culture when Diane refuses his marriage proposal?

Tags: dialogue, cheers

In *Cheers* season 5 episode 1, Diane refuses Sam's marriage proposal. She explains why, and Sam immediately takes on a different speech pattern and has a small monologue about 15 minutes in:

> Sam: Did you notice that?
>
> Diane: Notice what?
>
> Same: Everything just got calm.
>
> Diane: I don't notice any difference.
>
> Sam: Oh, yes, yes. There's a difference in everything. The whole world just changed for me. Oh! Look! The stars are new. The moon is new. Sam Malone is new, and I like him. And I like them, and they like me. And none of us like you.

The full script can be found [here](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=849&t=16755).

I couldn't find a clip in which he spoke this, but I didn't understand why this occurred and why it was funny (the laugh track plays at the end of this bit). English isn't my first language, so I figured there may have been some reference I was missing. Was this scene referencing something else, or were they just trying to portray Sam's incredulity and general animosity towards the situation?

Comment: The laugh track was probably used so the viewing audience would know that Sam wasn't being mean by saying it.  He just had an epiphany of sorts and decided he didn't care anymore.  He had previously stated that he always loved her, even when he was mad at her.  And after her rejection, he decided to look at the world differently.  Hence, "The stars are new.  The moon is new."